# How to add URL access date in Quarto pdf references

Tags: r, latex, pandoc, quarto

I am trying to add a *last accessed* field to web references in a Quarto PDF. Here is a minimal example of a `qmd` file:

```
---
title: "How to cite a URL with access date"
format: pdf
bibliography: references.bib
---

I am using @stackoverflow1, @stackoverflow2 and @stackoverflow3.

# References

::: {#refs}
:::
```

This is `references.bib`:

```
@online{stackoverflow1,
  title = {Stack Overflow with note},
  url   = {https://stackoverflow.com/},
  year  = {2022},
  note  = {https://stackoverflow.com/, last accessed on 2022-12-30}
}

@online{stackoverflow2,
  title   = {Stack Overflow with urldate},
  url     = {https://stackoverflow.com/},
  year    = 2022,
  urldate = {2022-12-30}
}

@online{stackoverflow3,
  title    = {Stack Overflow with accessed},
  url      = {https://stackoverflow.com/},
  year     = {2022},
  accessed = {2022-12-30}
}
```

The output is,

[image]

As you can see, the `note`, `urldate` and `accessed` fields are all ignored. I have tried using different `csl` files, e.g. [APA](http://www.zotero.org/styles/apa) and [Harvard Educational Review](http://www.zotero.org/styles/harvard-educational-review). I have also tried the instructions for doing this in Latex in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404227/url-date-access-missing) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111630/how-to-add-date-accessed-or-date-retrieved-in-biblatex) post. I have also changed `@misc` to `@online`. None of these seem to make any difference.

How do you add a date accessed field to a Quarto PDF reference?

### Expected output

> #### References
>
> "Stack Overflow", 2022, https://stackoverflow.com/, last accessed on 2022-12-30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell Quarto to use `biblatex` using [`cite-method`](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/pdf.html#references) yaml option.

```
---
title: "How to cite a URL with access date"
format: pdf
bibliography: references.bib
cite-method: biblatex
biblatexoptions:
  - citestyle = authoryear
---

I am using @stackoverflow1, @stackoverflow2 and @stackoverflow3.

# References

::: {#refs}
:::
```

---

[image: URL access date in Quarto pdf references]

---

`accessed` field is still being ignored but `urldate` and `note` is working as intended.

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful. The only thing is that the references now appear as e.g. _Stack Overflow with note [2]_, rather than _Stack Overflow with note (2022)_. This is the case even when I use either of the two `csl` files I linked in the question. Is there a way around this?

Comment: yes,  see the edit. `biblatex` has actually a lot options to control citations.

Comment: Thank you. I was reading about the `biblatex` options but I couldn't work out that key value pairs had to be in the form of `citestyle = authoryear`, rather than the typical `yaml` form of `citestyle: authoryear`. I don't know how you were able to but very much appreciated.

Comment: Got this idea from skimming through this [pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) a while ago.

Answer (score 5):

When used with CSL, then `urldate` is the correct way to add the access date to a reference. The used citation style must support that information, or otherwise it won't be shown. You can go to the citation style repository and search for `"accessed"` (which is the key used by CSL for this information). This will bring up all styles that include this info in the entry.

https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/search?q=accessed

Such styles are commonly called "author date styles", so we could also search for those [in the Zotero database](https://www.zotero.org/styles?format=author-date). To use a style, download it and pass it via the `csl` metadata key.

Comment: I did try to do just this but I wasn't sure that `"accessed"` was the correct term to search for and I didn't know about that repo, so this is an extremely useful response, thanks.

Comment: This is really an informative and useful answer. I have just bookmarked it.

Comment: @shafee Thanks, same for your answer! I learned about the `biblatexoptions` setting, didn't know about that one before.